# Multicolumn (Tables) trouble

Tags: tables, tabularx, wrap

I am trying to get my table working for last couple of days. But I couldnt fix the problem. The way I want my table to look like is below (figure 1).

[image]

With my following code

```
\begin{table}[p]
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
    \hline
    Compound               & \multicolumn{4}{c}{A}                                                                          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{B}                                                                         \\
    AT                     & \#1                     & \#2                    & \#1                    & \#2                    & \#1                    & \#2                    & \#1                    & \#2                    \\
    feedstock              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}                          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}                         \\ \hline
    Par 1                  & 1                      & 1                     & 2                     & 2                     & 3                     & 3                     & 4                     & 4                     \\
    Par 2                  & 1                      & 1                     & 2                     & 2                     & 3                     & 3                     & 4                     & 4                     \\
    Par 3                  & 1                      & 1                     & 2                     & 2                     & 3                     & 3                     & 4                     & 4                     \\
    Par 4                  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1}                          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2}                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3}                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4}                         \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{9}{l}{Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah} \\ \hline
\end{tabular} \end{table}
```

I am getting (figure 2):
[image]

I tried using tabularx and defined the size of each column. It worked until I added last long row (which is a merged form of all 9 columns). Also the the header "B" and last coulmn (figure 1) is going out of the page in figure 2.

It would be nice if someone can help me. Also, detailed explanation of the solution would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By using the `l` column type for the super-long word, you’ve disabled automatic line-breaking. Even if you chose a different column type, i.e., a column type that allows line breaking, how is LaTeX even supposed to decide how and where to insert line breaks in the super-long word?

Comment: Thanks, @Mico for your replay. I changed now a long word with a bunch of "Blah Blah"s (so latex should know where to break the line) and also changed column type from `l` to `c`. However, the problem isn't solved. Definitely, I am doing something wrong.

Comment: The `c`, `l`, and `r` column types do no allow line breaking.

Comment: we need to know your page layout and desired width of table. ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the "Blah Blah ..." material is only indirectly related to the preceding, table-like material. Is the "Blah Blah" material maybe some kind of legend? If this guess is correct, you'd be better off *not* placing it inside the `tabular` environment. Instead, I suggest you load the `threeparttable` package and place the legend in a `tablenotes` environment, which (thanks to the behind-the-scenes work of the `threeparttable` environment) will automatically be as wide as the preceding `tabular` environment.

In case you're curious about the name `threeparttable` of the package: It can handle three types of elements: The table caption (which is absent in the case of your code), the `tabular`-like material, and the `tablenotes` material. The package works, though, even if there is no caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{8}{c} @{}}
\hline
Compound  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{B} \\
AT  & \#1 & \#2 & \#1 & \#2 & \#1 & \#2 & \#1 & \#2 \\
feedstock & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} 
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} \\ 
\hline
 Par 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 4 \\
 Par 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 4 \\
 Par 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 4 \\
 Par 4 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2} 
       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[]Notes: Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mico ! I really liked this arrangement of having tablenotes. It precisely solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

since you tag your question with `tabularx` i suggest to use this package. beside it more nice result you will obtain by use of the `booktabs` package for horizontal rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[p]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} c *{8}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
Compound    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{A}         & \multicolumn{4}{c}{B}         \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(l){6-9}
    AT      & \#1   & \#2   & \#1   & \#2   & \#1   & \#2   & \#1   & \#2   \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
feedstock   & \mcc{C}       & \mcc{B}       & \mcc{C}       & \mcc{B}       \\
    \midrule
Par 1       & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 3     & 3     & 4     & 4     \\
Par 2       & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 3     & 3     & 4     & 4     \\
Par 3       & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 3     & 3     & 4     & 4     \\
Par 4       & \mcc{1}       & \mcc{2}       & \mcc{3}       & \mcc{4}       \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{9}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}{Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

Answer (score 1):

You can add width argument to your columns, like `\multicolumn{9}{p{\linewidth}}`. Perhaps `\multicolumn{9}{p{.7\linewidth}}` will do even better. Addding this to your example produces the following [image: output] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axj6X.jpg

Here is the complete code of mwe

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\hline
Compound               & \multicolumn{4}{c}{A}                                                                          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{B}                                                                         \\
AT                     & \#1                     & \#2                    & \#1                    & \#2                    & \#1                    & \#2                    & \#1                    & \#2                    \\
feedstock              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}                          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}                         \\ \hline
Par 1                  & 1                      & 1                     & 2                     & 2                     & 3                     & 3                     & 4                     & 4                     \\
Par 2                  & 1                      & 1                     & 2                     & 2                     & 3                     & 3                     & 4                     & 4                     \\
Par 3                  & 1                      & 1                     & 2                     & 2                     & 3                     & 3                     & 4                     & 4                     \\
Par 4                  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1}                          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2}                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3}                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4}                         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{9}{p{\linewidth}}{Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah} \\ \hline
\end{tabular} \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution has the (presumably unintended) side-effect of making the final column very wide indeed in case the combined width of the 9 columns is less than `\linewidth`. Can you think of a way of avoiding this issue?